# Twitter like fixed header

Tags: html, css, menu, header

How to create a fixed header like Twitter/Facebook on the top of the page ?

I am testing with this but when I am resizing my browser, complete design distorted

```
  <div id="head">
   <div id="logo">
    <a href="#"></a>
   </div>
   <div style="display:inline;">
    <input style="margin-top:3px;" class="searchbox" type="text"/>
   </div>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#" title="Home">Home</a> 
  <li>
  <li>
   <a href="#" title="Profile">Profile</a> 
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#" title="Profile">Actions</a> 
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#" title="Profile">Invite Friends</a> 
  </li>
 </ul>


</div>
<div id="content">
      </div>
```

Style

```
     html {
         height:100%; /* fix height to 100% for IE */
         max-height:100%; /* fix height for other browsers */
         padding:0; /*remove padding */
         margin:0; /* remove margins */

         background:#fff; /*color background - only works in IE */
         /* hide overflow:hidden from IE5/Mac */
         /* \*/
         overflow:hidden; /*get rid of scroll bars in IE */
         /* */
}
body {
         height:100%;
         max-height:100%;
         min-width:960px;
         overflow:hidden;
         padding:0;
         margin:0;
         font: 13px/1.5 Helvetica Neue,Arial,Helvetica,'Liberation Sans',FreeSans,sans-serif;
}
#content {
         display:block;
         height:100%;
         max-height:100%;
         overflow:auto;
         position:relative;
         z-index:3;
         word-wrap:break-word;
         top:45px;
}
#head {
         position:absolute;
         margin:0;
         top:0;
         display:block;
         width:100%;
         height:40px;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
         background:#333333;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #736F6E, #111111) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;

}
#logo a {
            background: url("2.gif") no-repeat scroll 6px 2px transparent;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            display: block;
            height: 100%;
            margin-right: 5px;
            outline: medium none;
            text-indent: -9999px;
            width: 140px;
           float:left;
}
.searchbox{
            -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #444444;
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #666666;
            border: 1px solid black;
            color: #CCCCCC;
            font: 13px Arial,sans-serif;
            padding: 6px 5px 4px 26px;
            width: 215px;
         float:right;
}

.searchbox:focus {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eeeeee;
            border: 1px solid #999999;
        }
#head ul {
          margin:0;
          padding:0;
          background:transparent;
          height:100%;
          margin-left:60px;
          padding-left:660px;
          padding-top:10px;
}
#head ul li {  display:inline;}
#head ul li a { padding-left:10px;  color:#BABABA; text-decoration:none;}
#head ul li a:hover { color:#FFFFFF;  }
```

**Edit**
*Sample*
http://jsfiddle.net/zerotoinfinite2006/tTmSH/embedded/result/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `#head` element needs to have fixed positioning to make it float at the top. This will make it stay at the top all of the time. Try using this

```
#head {
     position:fixed;
     margin:0px;
     top:0px;
     left:0px;
     display:block;
     width:100%;
     height:40px;
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     background:#333333;
     background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #736F6E, #111111) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
```

Comment: I have made position:fixed but still I am getting alignment issue. Menu is distorted when I tried to resize my broswer :-( any help ?

Comment: What do you mean by distorted? Does the size change?

Comment: Yes, Menu items left the header

Comment: You have a padding-left of 660px on the ul element. This means that once the browser window becomes narrow it is going to wrap to new lines because it has no space to go into.

Comment: This link will give you the code link http://jsfiddle.net/zerotoinfinite2006/tTmSH/3/

Comment: probably min-width will help me... I am not sure.. just a guess

Comment: Ok have a look at the jsfiddle now. I changed the ul element to float left and the li elements display inline. They don't drop down unless the searchbar runs into the menu. Once you've calculated a menu width set a min-width on the head and it should stop any problems

Comment: I guess, your changes will not be saved.. there. But I got your point. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at Twitter's bootstrap:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#navigation

You might be better just reusing it.

Comment: Thanks ! But do I need to pay them if that is being use by any commercial website ?

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite As the code is licensed under an Apache License v2.0, the answer is [no.](http://www.inteist.com/2010/05/how-to-use-apache-2-0-in-commercial-products-explained-in-simple-terms/)

Answer (score 1):

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>WebSpeaks.in</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="head">
   <div id="logo">
    <a href="#"></a>
   </div>
   <form style="display:inline;">
    <input style="margin-top:3px;" class="searchbox" type="text"/>
   </form>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#" title="Home">Home</a> 
  <li>
  <li>
   <a href="#" title="Profile">Profile</a> 
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#" title="Profile">Messages</a> 
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#" title="Profile">Who To Follow</a> 
  </li>
 </ul>


</div>
<div id="content">
 <div>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/02/how-to-hide-add-item-button-magento.html">How to hide 'Add Item' button in Magento Backend Grid</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/02/learn-method-chaining-with-advanced.html">Learn Simple Method Chaining in PHP </a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/02/create-simple-paint-canvas-using.html">Create Simple Paint Canvas using JavaScript</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/01/quickview-my-first-magento-extension.html">Quickview: My First Magento Extension</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/01/disabling-right-click-on-web-pagediv.html">Disabling Right Click on Web Page/DIV, Disabling Text Copy From a Web Page</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/01/google-like-instant-preview-using.html">Google like Instant Preview using jQuery & base64 Image Encoding in PHP</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/01/bubbly-image-gallery-with-jquery.html">Stylish Bubbly Image Gallery with jQuery</a></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><a href="http://www.webspeaks.in/2011/01/here-is-simple-script-showing-image.html">Image Zoom Effect with jQuery</a></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

The CSS:

```
html {
 height:100%; /* fix height to 100% for IE */
 max-height:100%; /* fix height for other browsers */
 padding:0; /*remove padding */
 margin:0; /* remove margins */
 border:0; /* remove borders */
 background:#fff; /*color background - only works in IE */
 /* hide overflow:hidden from IE5/Mac */
 /* \*/
 overflow:hidden; /*get rid of scroll bars in IE */
 /* */
}
body {
 height:100%;
 max-height:100%;
 overflow:hidden;
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 border:0;
    font: 13px/1.5 Helvetica Neue,Arial,Helvetica,'Liberation Sans',FreeSans,sans-serif;
}
#content {
 display:block;
 height:100%;
 max-height:100%;
 overflow:auto;
 padding-left:100px;
 position:relative;
 z-index:3;
 word-wrap:break-word;
 top:45px;
}
#head {
 position:absolute;
 margin:0;
 top:0;
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 height:40px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 background:#333333;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #333333, #111111) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
}
#logo a {
    background: url("twitter_logo_right.png") no-repeat scroll 20px 9px transparent;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    outline: medium none;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 140px;
 float:left;
}
.searchbox{
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #444444;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #666666;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: #CCCCCC;
    font: 13px Arial,sans-serif;
    padding: 6px 25px 4px 6px;
    width: 215px;
 float:left;
}

.searchbox:focus {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eeeeee;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
}
#head ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  background:transparent;
  height:100%;
  margin-left:60px;
  padding-left:60px;
  padding-top:10px;
}
#head ul li {  display:inline;}
#head ul li a { padding-left:20px;  color:#BABABA; text-decoration:none;}
#head ul li a:hover { color:#FFFFFF;  }

table tr td{height:100px; width:300px; -moz-border-radius:12px; background-color:#C6C6C6; margin:botton:30px;}
table tr td a{color: #007B9F; font-size:1.5em; text-decoration:none;}
```