# How can I create a fixed top bar?

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a black strip on the top of the page (used as the navigation system) and I want the position to be fixed, so when I scroll down on the page it will remain on the screen.

I'm unsure how it would be possible to allow it to be visible on the screen at all times & would I need to create a CSS to create the navigation strip, or insert a black box then CSS it to the top?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter like fixed header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8303273/twitter-like-fixed-header)

Comment: I'm not sure how you would create the black box *without* CSS, or how creating it with CSS would differ from somehow "CSSing" it after creation.

Comment: Ah sorry, I'll clarify :) I meant, do I need to create a black box & then alter it with the CSS or could I just create the CSS - I'm a newbie

Comment: There is no such thing as "alter it with CSS". Either you have a CSS rule or not: it's not meaningful to talk about "altering with CSS" and "creating CSS"--they're the same thing. (You *can* use JavaScript to change an element's styling but that wouldn't be useful in this case.)

Comment: And didn't you ask this [same question a week ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258283/creating-a-navigation-bar-fixed-on-the-top-of-screen) that got practically the same answers?

Comment: Thanks for your response Juhana, but if you were paying enough attention to the "same question" I posted a week ago you would notice that it didn't resolve my issue.

Answer (score 16):

CSS

```
#blackBar{
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;
   background-color:black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LzDR7/

Comment: the code pushes other stuff off to the right.

Answer (score 1):

In the div that is this black strip, set its "position" property to "fixed" in the css like this:

```
position: fixed;
```

Comment: Ah thanks, how would I add buttons onto it & keep the position fixed as well then? Would they need to be a separate name on the CSS?

Comment: You need to research into HTML and css more. Visit w3schools.com or code academy so you can get a better understanding of how html & css work.